# SQL C# Doubles with decimals

Tags: c#, sql, double, decimal

I'm trying to enter a double value in an SQL update statment, which is already converted (see code 1), to keep his numbers behind the comma.

(1)

```
double.TryParse(splitline[8], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out natMB //conversion
```

(2) Putting my value in an procedure to my SQL statement, i putted natMB into 'Verbruikgegevens', index position 2. 0 or 1 indicates if my inputted data is roaming or not. This is a part of an if statement declaring weither it's roaming or national data.

```
sqlStatementUpdate(TrafficdataID, 0,     
(Convert.ToDouble(Verbruikgegevens.Rows[intCount].ItemArray[2],   
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

(3) SQL statement in Visual studio (C#)

```
public void sqlStatementUpdate(long TrafficdataID, byte Roaming, double Value)
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.Connection = connection2;
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SP_SCTrafficdataDetailUpdate";
    DataAccessHelper.AddParam(sqlCmd, "TDDValue", SqlDbType.Decimal, Convert.ToDecimal(Value));
    DataAccessHelper.AddParam(sqlCmd, "TrafficdataID", SqlDbType.BigInt, TrafficdataID);
    DataAccessHelper.AddParam(sqlCmd, "TDDRoaming", SqlDbType.Bit, Roaming);
    DataAccessHelper.ExecSProcDS(sqlCmd);
}
```

(4) DataAccesHelper

```
internal static class DataAccessHelper
{
    public static void AddParam(SqlCommand cmd, string columnName, SqlDbType dbType, object paramvalue)
    {
        if (paramvalue is DateTime)
        {
            if (((DateTime)paramvalue).Date == DateTime.MinValue.Date)
            {
                paramvalue = DBNull.Value;
            }

        }

        if (paramvalue == null)
        {
            paramvalue = DBNull.Value;
        }

        string param = "@" + columnName;
        if (!cmd.Parameters.Contains(param))
        {
            if (dbType == SqlDbType.VarChar || dbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar || dbType == SqlDbType.Char || dbType == SqlDbType.NChar)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param, dbType, 4000);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param, dbType);

            cmd.Parameters[param].SourceColumn = columnName;
            cmd.Parameters[param].Value = paramvalue;
        }
    }

    public static DataSet ExecSProcDS(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

(5) SQL statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SCTrafficdataDetailUpdate] @TDDValue decimal, @TrafficdataID bigint, @TDDRoaming bit
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE    TR_SCTrafficDataDetail
SET              TDDValue = @TDDValue
WHERE     (TDDType = 'Data') AND (TrafficDataID = @TrafficdataID) AND (TDDRoaming = @TDDRoaming)
END
```

QUESTION: Is it possible that I keep using a double, and also keep my numbers behind the comma when importing the data to my sqltable? Right now it doesn't seem to work that wel ... I defined my Value in my SQLTable as an decimal though

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in your question... Anyway, if you work with `Decimal` fields in the database, I'd suggest you use `Decimal` variables in C# to keep things compatible and/or avoid round-off errors.

Comment: Doesn't decimals slow down performance?

Comment: You're missing a question. Is sql stripping away the fractional part of your number you try to insert?

Comment: Decimal may be slightly slower than double, but it really depends on what your question really is. Are you willing to give up some speed for accuracy?

Comment: Id rather not actually .. I'm using the program to scan daily textfiles from over 10000 records, having a debug speed of 15m now, like to keep it that way ...

Comment: 15min for handling just 10000 records sounds like there is something wrong with your all over design, I think if you fix the design flaw you can just use decimal and not have the issue in the first place.

Comment: I would just use decimal, the overhead is small whilst keeping data exact, whilst double will skew real values

Comment: Argh .. i inferred debug speed in decimal `decimal debugspeed =15m;` :) why not check the performance once you change to decimal you already have the benchmark for doubles

Comment: Your problem isn't SQL at all you hasn't successfully converted the number within C# because your specifying the invariant culture which uses a dot as decimal separator but you are using a comma. You need to either manipulate the string or specify the format or specify the correct culture.

Comment: @V4Vendetta, changed everything to decimal. Used a little test file and still a 0 pops up e.g. 325754,88 in my console output turns into 325759.00 in my SQL table.

Comment: @Ben How do I specificy my correct culture when using comma's?

Comment: You specify the correct culture name or number instead of using Invariant. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx. Alternatively if you know the data is always the same you can use a format string withh parse. In yoru case it is probably best to just do `val = val.Replace(",", ".")`

Comment: Replace doesn't work for me. On the other hand, I still don't get a decimal output at my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question is:

- I have text input representing numbers, using sometimes a comma and sometimes a period for the decimal separator. How can I convert these reliably to numbers?

Answer: This has nothing to do with the SQL data types. You need to first write reliable C# code to convert the number to a double or decimal. Either will do - you should use whichever one matches your database.

The Invariant culture REQUIRES the period as a decimal point, NOT the comma. So you are using the wrong culture if you have commas as decimal separator.

If you know what format your numbers are in, use the overloaded Parse and specify the format directly.

If it is from user input, use the user's culture, OR train the user what format to use.

Finally, if you have some odd format, you might need to write your own code to regularise the format using regexes.

**Speed issues**

10000 rows is nothing it should take seconds not minutes.

I notice you are creating a new SqlCommand for each row. Each time you do so it has to go to the SQL server and match up the metadata with the stored proc you are calling.

Just create it once, and re-use it by setting the values to the values from the new row. Just don't forget to set the NULL ones to DBNull.Value.

Comment: For the speed issues. You mean defning it once, and call upon another procedure to change the variables within the command?

Comment: I do not think it will work that way, won't I get an overloop of adding parameters?

Comment: You only add them once, when you create the SqlCommand, setting the value to DBNull.Value. then you say `cmdObject.Parameters["@paramName"].Value = valueVariable;`